# excel conditional formatting based on greater/less than in adjacent cell/column

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

[image]

Hey there I am trying to get `Column E` to highlight Green when `Column F>0.59`, I have read through how to do it to some extent, but my issue is that my spreadsheet is close to 60 entries long with about 30 sets of data going horizontally. So I am trying to figure out what my rule needs to be so that I can do multiple rows at a time.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Above link shows the different options I've tried that do not work

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the columns you want to edit
2. Go to Conditional Formatting
3. Highlight Cell Rules > New Formatting Rule
4. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
5. Enter the rule you want (=F5>0.59)
6. Select the Format option to highlight green then click OK
7. Now with the highlight column selected, go back to Conditional Formatting > 8. Manage Rules
8. Under "Applies to" change the column to E:E
9. Click OK - you're done

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/ccYhc.png Still not getting any formatting changes

Comment: It looks like your column F is in percentages, meaning you should probably change the rule knowing that 1 = 100%, so 0.59 = 59%. Try changing the rule to =F5>0.0059

Answer (score 0):

1- Select column `E` from `E5` downward

2- Menu `Home --> Conditional Formatting --> New Rule`

3- Select `Us a Formula...`

4- In the formula box, enter this:

```
=F5>.59
```

5- Click `Format` and select the format you want. As per your question you want a `fill` of green.

That's it! the formula although written with `E5` in mind, will adjust for the other rows, so long as CF formula is "relative" (no `$` used) to the first selected cell.